# HTML and Javascript, function is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I can't figure out why my function "validate()" is coming up as undefined.

```
<FORM NAME="page" ACTION="findClientLOSAction.epl" METHOD="POST" TARGET="_blank"
 ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">

<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="userName" VALUE="[+ $userName +]">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="sessionId" VALUE="[+ $sessionId +]">

<TABLE WIDTH="100%" CLASS="FORM">
  <TR CLASS="FORM">
    <TD>
    </TD>
    <TD>
      <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="loanNumber" id="loanNumber">
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>

<TABLE WIDTH="100%" CLASS="FORM">
  <TR>
    <TD ALIGN="CENTER">
      <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="action" VALUE="Open LOS" CLASS="BUTTON"
            onClick="return validate()">
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Then my JS comes in and tries to validate the input with a Regex match. But it is undefined.

```
function validate() {

 var loanNumber = document.querySelector('#loanNumber');
 match = loanNumber.test(\d{3}-\d{1,8});    # 3 digits followed by a hyphen followed by 1 to 8 digits

 if (! match) {
     alert("Invalid Loan Number: " loanNumber);
     return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

Comment: Why are your tags in caps?

Comment: that isn't how you write regexp literal, try `.test(/\d{3}-\d{1,8}/)` (notice the `/` wrapping characters) and if this solves your issues let us know so we can close the question due to a "typo"

Comment: Where is your script tag in relation to your html? If it's above it, there's your problem.

Comment: Why are you using `querySelector` for an ID? `getElementById` is faster

Comment: You should also use an event handler instead of inline scripting. It's bad practice. Check out `addEventListener`

Comment: @Jnatalzia Why would that be a problem? The function is called from inline handler, it should exist at the time user clicks the button. Multiple syntax errors in the code causes the function being not defined.

Comment: `alert("Invalid Loan Number: " loanNumber);` <-- syntax error

Comment: Seems like a good opportunity to improve your debugging skills. Read these articles to [learn](http://juliepagano.com/blog/2014/05/18/javascript-debugging-for-beginners) [how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Comment: The general answer to these kind of problems is: Either your function is not defined in the scope (chain) where you are trying to access it, or the part of the code where the function definition is located could not be evaluated (e.g. because of a syntax error). In both cases, debugging helps.

Comment: @SterlingArcher legacy code. All 600k line of embedded perl are in caps.
Ok so i took all your advice (thank you!) and now my syntax seems a bit better. I'm still having the undefined issue though. My script tags are after the html but I didn't think that would break it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `var loanNumber = document.querySelector('#loanNumber');` returns a DOM element, not a string. `test()` is a function of the `RegExp` class and `\d{3}-\d{1,8}` is not a valid regular expression.
Code should be:

```
function validate() {
     var loanNumber = document.querySelector('#loanNumber').value;

     var regex = RegExp('\d{3}-\d{1,8}');
     var match = regex.test(loanNumber);    

     if (! match) {
         alert("Invalid Loan Number: " +loanNumber);
         return false;
     }
     return true;

    }
```

A good way of debugging your code would be to try and run every piece of code individually see if it breaks. Also the browser should tell which line is the problem.

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot. I actually figured out it was the # comment that was breaking it. My IDE colorizes for perl syntax and not JS in the same file so I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

`loanNumber` returns a `DOM element`, you want the actual value.

The syntax for `.match` is `REGEX.match(TESTSTRING)`.

And when writing an alert, the entire thing has to be encapsulated in a string, so `alert("Invalid Loan Number: " loanNumber);` is invalid.

You want:

```
function validate() {

 var loanNumber = document.querySelector('#loanNumber').value;
 var match = (/\d{3}-\d{1,8}/).test(loanNumber);
 // # 3 digits followed by a hyphen followed by 1 to 8 digits

 if (! match) {
     alert("Invalid Loan Number: " + loanNumber);
     return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```